# Some questions on x86 assembly language?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64, simd

I just begin to learn asm language, get a few questions:

1) How to allocate aligned memory block through assembly langauge like we did so often in C/C++?

2) Is there some asm maths library that covers some basic math ops/functions like these we can find in standard C/C++ math libraries/headers etc?

Comment: Try breaking these up into more specific single questions and you'll get a better response

Comment: OK... get my questions shortened...

Comment: You can use the GNU C Library with assembly.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Assembly, it is up to you and the OS.  Allocating memory in Windows, you would use the Heap* or Virtual* memory API functions.  In Linux, you need to change the program break to allocate memory.
2. Math libraries?!?!  We use Assembly to learn how to do things on our own, that is the fun part - experimenting and learning.  If you want to use libraries, just use C/C++  otherwise search for math libraries.